# Ruby: assign and check if nil in one line

Tags: ruby

I have a function defined like...

```
def create_button(content)
  title = content.dig(0, 'text')
  url = content.dig(0, 'url')

  return nil if title.nil? || url.nil?

  return Button.new(
    title,
    url
  )
end
```

Or something...

Anyway, I was wondering if it would be possible to smoosh those first few lines together and do the assignment, nil check and return in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
def create_button(content)
  title, url = content[0]&.values_at('text', 'url')
  return nil if title.nil? || url.nil?

  Button.new(title, url)
end
```

Comment: Will `content[0]` error if the `content` array contains no values?

Comment: That works! Thanks I didn't know about `values_at` :)

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Comment: The guard clause can probably be shortened to `return unless title && url`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But I tend to avoid unless when I have a compound condition

Answer (score 1):

You can multiple assign values like this:

```
a, b = 'a', 'b'
```

When you have one result, like `return nil`, you could have two conditions in your if.

```
return nil if a.nil? or b.nil?
```

Or use `any?`

```
return nil if [a, b].any?(&:nil?)
```

So, the & symbol here is a shortcut to create a lambda, or reusable code block. It will try to run the method `nil?` on each item in the array. You can use this for other enumerable methods such as `each`, `select`, `reject` or `detect`.

Here's a nice short form of your method, doing all the same things:

```
def create_button(content)
  title, url = content.dig(0, 'text'), content.dig(0, 'url')
  return nil if [title,url].any(&:nil?)
  return Button.new(title, url)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is

```
def create_button(content)
  title = content.dig(0, 'text')
  url = content.dig(0, 'url')

  return nil if title.nil? || url.nil?

  return Button.new(
    title,
    url
  )
end
```

because either the title or url is nil you are returning nil.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to put these together as I realised I had not done this.

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but how does your code differ from the one in the question?

Comment: @spickermann I think they must have been responding to my code before my edit.